# Individually Responsive jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

When I try to duplicate my accordion for multiple dropdowns, it opens all and closes all, not individually. I tried to rename the second one to accordion2, and it will open, but not close. A third one doesn't work at all. I am new and just don't know what to do to make it work so I can have three accordions that work independently. PLEASE Help! Thank you.

```
<!--ACCORDION-->
        <h1 id="homeTitles">Cory Delancey</h1>
        <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Cory Delancey</a>

        <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
            <img class="guidesImg" src="images/campingRV.jpg">
            <p><strong>Certification: </strong>4L</p>
            <p><strong>Years of Experience: </strong>9</p>
            <p><strong>Email: </strong>cory@sra.com</p>
            <p><strong>Biography: </strong>Cory grew up in New York City, but each summer his family left the city to spend time backpacking and whitewater rafting. He came to Idaho for college and never left the state. He spends his summers as a guide on the rivers he loves.</p>
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
    </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
</div><!--end .accordion-->

</main>


/* GUIDES ACCORDION 1 */
.accordion, .accordion * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    box-sizing:border-box; }

.accordion {
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#f7f7f7; }

/* ACCORDION titles */
.accordion-section-title {
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1a1a1a;
    background:#619efc;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    /* Type */
    font-size:1.200em;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
    color:#fff; }

.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
    background:#4c4c4c; text-decoration:none; }

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
    border-bottom:none; }

/* ACCORDION Content */
.accordion-section-content { padding:15px; display:none; }

/* ACCORDION Images */
.guidesImg{  float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }


/*GUIDES PAGES*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

            // Add active class to section title
            $(this).addClass('active');
            // Open up the hidden content panel
            $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `close_accordion_section()` to close a specific panel by having it accept a variable, then pass the specific title section that was clicked (or all that weren't clicked) as the variable when you call that function, and reference the elements that are positioned relative to the title you clicked to close a panel.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function close_accordion_section($el) {
    $el.removeClass("active");
    $el.next(".accordion-section-content").slideUp(300).removeClass("open");
  }
  
  var $titles = $(".accordion-section-title");

  $titles.on('click',function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr("href");

    if ($(e.target).is(".active")) {
      close_accordion_section($(this));
    } else {
      close_accordion_section($titles.not($(this)));
      // Add active class to section title
      $(this).addClass("active");
      // Open up the hidden content panel
      $(".accordion " + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass("open");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
/* GUIDES ACCORDION 1 */
.accordion, .accordion * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

/* ACCORDION titles */
.accordion-section-title {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  background: #619efc;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  /* Type */
  font-size: 1.200em;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
  background: #4c4c4c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

/* ACCORDION Content */
.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}

/* ACCORDION Images */
.guidesImg {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--ACCORDION-->
<h1 id="homeTitles">Cory Delancey</h1>
<div class="accordion">

  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Cory Delancey</a>

    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
      <img class="guidesImg" src="images/campingRV.jpg">
      <p><strong>Certification: </strong>4L</p>
      <p><strong>Years of Experience: </strong>9</p>
      <p><strong>Email: </strong>cory@sra.com</p>
      <p><strong>Biography: </strong>Cory grew up in New York City, but each summer his family left the city to spend time backpacking and whitewater rafting. He came to Idaho for college and never left the state. He spends his summers as a guide on the
        rivers he loves.</p>
    </div>
    <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Cory Delancey</a>

    <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
      <img class="guidesImg" src="images/campingRV.jpg">
      <p><strong>Certification: </strong>4L</p>
      <p><strong>Years of Experience: </strong>9</p>
      <p><strong>Email: </strong>cory@sra.com</p>
      <p><strong>Biography: </strong>Cory grew up in New York City, but each summer his family left the city to spend time backpacking and whitewater rafting. He came to Idaho for college and never left the state. He spends his summers as a guide on the
        rivers he loves.</p>
    </div>
    <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3">Cory Delancey</a>

    <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
      <img class="guidesImg" src="images/campingRV.jpg">
      <p><strong>Certification: </strong>4L</p>
      <p><strong>Years of Experience: </strong>9</p>
      <p><strong>Email: </strong>cory@sra.com</p>
      <p><strong>Biography: </strong>Cory grew up in New York City, but each summer his family left the city to spend time backpacking and whitewater rafting. He came to Idaho for college and never left the state. He spends his summers as a guide on the
        rivers he loves.</p>
    </div>
    <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-->
</div>
<!--end .accordion-->

</main>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you! I'm so new at this--I have spend the better part of the day trying to fix and figure this out--I cannot thank you enough for your kind generosity.